# Which widget is used in Visual Studio's central widget?

Tags: qt, user-interface

I want to use Qt to build a GUI with a central widget like the visual studio. The widget has a number of tabbed windows to edit h/cpp files. Which widget should I use?

Comment: Neither. You should create your own. And it's complex task. If you create such widget with Qt - you may cell it, because it will be demanded.

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest thing you can find to replicate the visual studio tabbed windows is [QMdiArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmdiarea.html). But if you want the full functionality of Visual Studio's tabbed widgets you need to implement your own widget.

Answer (score 2):

You can create only something similar to Visual Studio using Qt classes. Central widget should also have layout. Only `QMainWindow` has `setCentralWidget` method.

`QTextEdit` with `QSyntaxHighlighter` to make your text with color.

`QMenu` requires also `QAction`. You can also use `QToolBar`

`QSplitter` allows you to move(resize widgets)

`QLineEdit` for small texts (for example search word or something else)

Description:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem and found a library that adds the ability to use similar layouts as VS do: dynamically resizable, stackable (horizontally, vertically, on each other), undockable, closable, saveable.

https://github.com/githubuser0xFFFF/Qt-Advanced-Docking-System
It has its own issues (at least on Linux), but it's a good point to start, anyway.